# Using a variable from a dictionary in a loop to attach to an API call

Tags: python, python-requests, linkedin-api

I'm calling a LinkedIn API with the code below and it does what I want.
However when I use almost identical code inside a loop it returns a type error.

it returns a type error:

```
File "C:\Users\pchmurzynski\OneDrive - Centiq Ltd\Documents\Python\mergedreqs.py", line 54, in <module>
    auth_headers = headers(access_token)
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

It has a problem with this line (which again, works fine outside of the loop):

```
headers = headers(access_token)
```

I tried changing it to

```
headers = headers.get(access_token)
```

or

```
headers = headers[access_token]
```

**EDIT:**
I have also tried this, with the same error:

```
auth_headers = headers(access_token)
```

But it didn't help. What am I doing wrong? Why does the dictionary work fine outside of the loop, but not inside of it and what should I do to make it work?

What I am hoping to achieve is to get a list, which I can save as json with share statistics called for each ID from the "shids" list. That can be done with individual requests - one link for one ID,

```
(f'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A77487&ugcPosts=List(urn%3Ali%3AugcPost%3A{shid})
```

or a a request with a list of ids.

```
(f'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A77487&ugcPosts=List(urn%3Ali%3AugcPost%3A{shid},urn%3Ali%3AugcPost%3A{shid2},...,urn%3Ali%3AugcPost%3A{shidx})
```

**Updated Code** thanks to your comments.

```
shlink = ("https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A77487&shares=List(urn%3Ali%3Ashare%3A{})")
#loop through the list of share ids and make an api request for each of them
shares = []
token = auth(credentials) # Authenticate the API
headers = fheaders(token) # Make the headers to attach to the API call.
for shid in shids:
    #create a request link for each sh id
    r = (shlink.format(shid))
    #call the api
    res = requests.get(r, headers = auth_headers)
    share_stats = res.json()
    #append the shares list with the responce
    shares.append(share_stats["elements"])
```

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace of the error, it usually contains valuable information

Comment: I believe the error changed when you used headers[access_token], what happened?

Comment: In the second snippet, `shids, requests, auth, headers` are not defined. For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including complete but minimal code, example input, and expected output. You can [edit]. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: File "C:\Users\pchmurzynski\OneDrive - Centiq Ltd\Documents\Python\mergedreqs.py", line 59, in <module>
    headers = headers(access_token) # Make the headers to attach to the API call.
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: Yes, we can see the error when you use `headers(access_token)`, but the error will be different if you used `headers[access_token]` or `headers.get(access_token)`, but you've not said what they are

Comment: Possible duplicates: [TypeError: 'str' object is not callable for user input](/q/56629936/4518341), [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in python](/q/31087111/4518341)

Comment: thanks for all the comments. I have just amended the first post, so you can see he whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> works fine outside the loop

Because in the loop, you re-define the variable. Added print statments to show it

```
from liapiauth import auth, headers  # one type

for ...:
    ... 
    print(type(headers))
    headers = headers(access_token)  # now set to another type
    print(type(headers))
```

Lesson learned - don't overrwrite your imports

---

Some refactors - your auth token isn't changing, so don't put it in the loop; You can use one method for all LinkedIn API queries

```
from liapiauth import auth, headers
import requests

API_PREFIX = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2'

SHARES_ENDPOINT_FMT = '/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A77487&shares=List(urn%3Ali%3Ashare%3A{}'

def get_linkedin_response(endpoint, headers):
    return requests.get(API_PREFIX + endpoint, headers=headers)

def main(access_token=None):
    if access_token is None:
       raise ValueError('Access-Token not defined')
    auth_headers = headers(access_token)

    shares = []
    for shid in shids:
        endpoint = SHARES_ENDPOINT_FMT.format(shid)
        resp = get_linkedin_response(endpoint, auth_headers)
        if resp.status_code // 100 == 2: 
            share_stats = resp.json()
            shares.append(share_stats[1])

    # TODO: extract your data here
    idlist = [el["id"] for el in shares_list["elements"]]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    credentials = 'credentials.json'
    main(auth(credentials))
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for that, but i still get the same error. This time for the line auth_headers = headers(access_token)

I amended the first post

Comment: You are still redefining headers on line 13 of your code:
headers = headers(access_token) # Make the headers to attach to the API call.

Comment: @PiotrChmurzynski You have two sections of `if __name__ == '__main__':`. You should only have one